# Please help identify red stemmed, green and white (and sometimes red) leafed plant

Tags: identification

My mother purchased this plant from a nursery in Western North Carolina about 1 1/2 years ago and it has grown substantially since the original purchase.  This plant is currently in a pot.  During spring and summer the plant is out on the back porch, during the fall and winter the plant is on her bathroom counter by the window.  Any thoughts on what this plant is?

The best way to describe the plant is that it has a red vine that runs up as far as the leaf but the redness does not go into the veins of the leaves.  The leaves are green and white but some of the leaves have a half with red in it.  Up to this point there has been no sign of the possibility of flowering.  I apologize for the quality of the pictures...my mom isn't the most technically savvy individual.

Thank you for your help!

[image: Plant]
[image: Plant1]
[image: Plant2]

Comment: So pretty. I have one too and thanks for the care instructions. Mine has red in leaves too. It’s leggy so I’ll follow instructions and hope I don’t kill her.

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately, this plant is easily recognisable, so the pics are okay, despite your mother's  'lack of technical savvy', a trait she probably shares with many moms (ncluding me!).

The plant is Iresine herbstii - the leaves look a little small compared to the thickness of the stems, so I wonder whether its outgrown its current pot and hasn't enough root room - I can't say because the whole plant and its container are not visible. If the plant doesn't get any sun where its growing, it might be Iresine 'brilliantissima' which usually has red/pink leaves, but tends to colour up less in duller light situations - if it does get sunlight, but remains this green yellow colour apart from the odd red bit here and there, its likely Iresine aureoreticulata. It does flower sometimes, but the flowers are insignificant and may not even be noticed - this plant is grown for its variegated leaves. Can be grown outdoors during summer in cooler regions (as you're doing currently), year round in warmer ones, see here http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/foliage/bloodleaf/bloodleaf-plant-care.htm

Comment: I agree with Bamboo (thank goodness) grins.  Your plant is not very healthy.  From what little we can see, your plant needs more light, less fertilizer and to begin, it could use pruning.  Take off the terminal buds/apical buds.  This will encourage denser versus this leggy growth.  I also am worried about the amount of misshapen leaves.  What you are doing for light sounds perfect...putting this plant outside for the summer and great light for the winter.  What type of soil is this plant in, please a pic to show plant and pot together. My sense is telling me too much high nitrogen fertilizer?